# How to get LSP like formatting in Org Mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here is a scenario I use constantly in development:

1. LSP is always on.
2. I call the LSP feature "format current buffer" (or whatever it's called).
3. The LSP returns the buffer formatted (internally, the LSP uses `rustfmt`).

I know there is no LSP implementation for Org Mode, but maybe it is still possible to achieve this?
E.g., I wanna press some button and have the Org Mode syntax formatted. For example: add an empty line after each heading, remove redundant spaces between heading stars and the text, underline in red if there is a syntax error in a header of a block, and etc.

P.S.
Emacs newbie here, transitioning from Neovim.